# dpkg error trying to install mongodb

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Not very familiar with these dpkg errors, I guess it could be that I have broken apt sources?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-iostreams1.71.0
  libboost-program-options1.71.0 libgoogle-perftools4 libpcrecpp0v5
  libsnappy1v5 libtcmalloc-minimal4 libyaml-cpp0.6 mongo-tools
  mongodb-server-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/90.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 147 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 131946 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_4.4.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.4.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.4.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-database-tools_100.2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-database-tools (100.2.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.2.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@configsfun:~# sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-iostreams1.71.0
  libboost-program-options1.71.0 libgoogle-perftools4 libpcrecpp0v5
  libsnappy1v5 libtcmalloc-minimal4 libyaml-cpp0.6 mongo-tools
  mongodb-server-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/90.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 147 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 131946 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_4.4.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.4.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.4.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-database-tools_100.2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-database-tools (100.2.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.2.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt purge mongodb-*` to purge all old mongodb packages

`dpkg -l | grep mongo` to check if something mongo-related left to uninstall:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep mongo
ii  mongo-tools                                3.6.3-0ubuntu1                        amd64        collection of tools for administering MongoDB servers
```

`sudo apt purge mongo-tools` and then try to install newer mongodb again.

Comment: I had to do `sudo apt purge mongo*`

Answer (score 3):

This happens because there is already a mongodb installation in you computer that came with ubuntu. You can find detailed solution [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/installation-ubuntu-community-troubleshooting/). I recommend you check it out. I will list the solution below for convenience.

Run the following commands in a terminal or shell to fully remove the Ubuntu mongodb package before retrying the installation procedure:

```
sudo apt remove mongodb
sudo apt purge mongodb
sudo apt autoremove
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched a great deal for this answer -- this is the only answer that worked in 2021 (has to do with purging and reinstalling properly):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48871898/6541639